# Loop through records

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python

I have written a python script that is supposed to basically loop through selected records of a feature class.  Here's a sample of what a table looks like:

```
OBID   STID FL  TL      
1   1   0   9       
2   1   8   19      
3   2   3   23      
4   3   0   0       
5   1   21  29      
6   3   0   11      
7   1   27  31      
8   3   13  19
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Create a SearchCursor (for main file) and InsertCursor (for new file)
2. Sort all records by STID, FL and TL in order with the SearchCursor
3. Record TL for the first row and move onto next row
4. Record STID and FL in a variable
5. Compare current FL to previous TL
6. If FL<=TL, export both rows to new table with InsertCursor
7. Continue until current STID is equal to previous STID. If not, go back to step 3 (ie, repeat the process for new STID)

And here's the code I wrote which is not working:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:\\temp\\test.mdb"
abc = arcpy.SearchCursor("road","","","STID;FL;TL","STID A;FL A;TL A")
first = 1
for row in abc:
     if first != 1:
         spid = row.getValue("STID")
         frl = row.getValue("FL")
             if spid == prev:
                 if frl <= trl:
                    print spid, frl
                    prev = row.getValue("STID")
                    trl = row.getValue("TL")
             else:
                  prev = row.getValue("STID")
                  trl = row.getValue("TL")
      else:
         prev = row.getValue("STID")
         trl = row.getValue("TL")
         first = 0
del row
del abc
```

Comment: Could you be a little more clear on the question? Did you want help actually writing the routine? Or because the code is throwing an error (which I assumed below, but now that I re-read the question, may not be the case)?

Comment: Also, if the code is throwing an error, could you post what it was?

Answer (score 6):

The logic behind what you're doing is somewhat unclear, but it sounds like you're trying to sort a bunch of records on a few different fields and then go through them one at a time trying to compare each record with some previous record based on the `STID` field and if neighboring records don't have the same `STID` field, then you move to the next until they match.

I think the trouble you're getting into, and this is a shot in the dark, is that search cursors don't support looping backwards. So if you're looking for `STID-x` and you iterate through your search cursor rows looking for `STID-y == STID-x`, you may end up at the end of your cursor object before you've done your complete analysis on each record. You can add some `print` statements to see what's going on for each iteration in your search cursor to help pinpoint where your script is going wrong.

Also, based on the fields and data you supplied above, it looks like you want to be comparing the `OBID` field to the `STID` field. If that's the case you need to re-look at your sorting and your `getValue` statements.

EDIT:

Ok, I got this to work. It looks like your problem was caused because you don't have a 'proper' Object ID for your rows. Not quite sure why this works, but I added a field called `FID` in Access and set it's type to 'AutoNumber' which stores a unique value for each record (even though your OBID field is unique already). Maybe someone else can enlighten us both. After doing that, I added logic to scrape your records from the 'roads' table into a new table called 'output' which is either created from scratch or cleared of any pre-existing data each time you run this script.

```
import arcpy
ws = 'C:/temp/test.mdb'
arcpy.env.workspace = ws
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor('road','','','STID;FL;TL','STID A; FL A; TL A')

#-- create new table to hold results using 'road' table as template
if arcpy.Exists('output'):
    arcpy.DeleteRows_management('output') #-- clear contents of output table
else:
    arcpy.CreateTable_management(ws,'output','road')
    arcpy.AddField_management('output','originalFID','LONG')

irows = arcpy.InsertCursor('output')  #-- create insert cursor

first = True
for row in rows:
    if first:
        first = False
    else:
        fid = row.FID
        stid = row.STID
        fl = row.FL
        tl = row.TL
        if stid == prev_stid and fl <= prev_tl:
            #-- add previous record to new table
            irow = irows.newRow()
            irow.originalFID = prev_fid
            irow.STID = prev_stid
            irow.TL = prev_tl
            irow.FL = prev_fl
            irows.insertRow(irow)
            del irow

            #-- now let's add the current record
            irow = irows.newRow()
            irow.originalFID = fid
            irow.STID = stid
            irow.TL = tl
            irow.FL = fl
            irows.insertRow(irow)
            del irow

            print stid,fl

    #-- let's store all information from this row
    prev_fid = row.FID
    prev_stid = row.STID
    prev_tl = row.TL
    prev_fl = row.FL

del rows,irows
```

Comment: @Sam Editing an answer is not an acceptable way to provide comments.  I believe you are able to comment on answers to your own question.  If not, you definitely can edit your question itself, provided this is an improvement to the question and not just a way to carry out a conversation.

Comment: For the record, so it does not get lost, here is the comment Sam would like to make: "Jason, The logic I used was that once the table is sorted using searchcursor, all that the code has to do is go to the next row and then compare like enumerated rows . But again, I'm new to all this and it might not make any sense. Can you suggest me how I should go about this? Thanks."

Comment: @Sam, without seeing your data I'm having trouble coming up with any solution for you here, though I posted an edit to my answer above to start off with.

Comment: An excerpt of the data appears at the beginning of the question.  +1 for your effort and for cleaning up the code, though.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. See updated code...

Comment: I wish I could upvote it again :-).

Comment: @jason, thank you very much for taking time to write the code. But unfortunately, the output table is not exactly what its supposed to look like. There are 6 pairs of records that shouldn't be in the table. records with fl>tl are also exported to the output table. I can't post the screenshot of the table. It would have been a lot easier to explain. Is there anyway I can send you the image file?

Comment: I updated line 27. Was comparing current TL and FL values; now compares previous TL and current FL values.

Comment: @sam, was this helpful?

Comment: Hey @sam, if this was useful to you I'd appreciate it if you'd "accept" this answer and help me out in my quest to amass stackexchange points and for world domination...

Answer (score 2):

Well, I copied your script and the test data. The only error I could see was in the second line, where you set the workspace - backslash is an escape character in Python.

There are four reasonably common alternatives. Double backslash (escapes the escape):

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:\\temp\\test.mdb"
```

Raw strings (prefix r):

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"c:\temp\test.mdb"
```

Triple quotes:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = """c:\temp\test.mdb"""
```

And forward slashes:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/temp/test.mdb"
```

Choose one that works for you. And there are more.

Comment: om_henners, The code doesn't give any error messages when I run it. It runs but gives unexpected result: 3 0.0 I am not sure how or why. And python recognizes 2 backslashes for path. I don't think that is a problem. Its the loop. It would be awesome if you or anybody can help me figure this out. Thanks.